# На чем лучше писать драйверы?

Tags: драйвер

На чем лучше писать драйверы? 
Или начать изучение написание драйверов?

//может литературка какая имеется? (лучше на русском)

Answer (score 2):

Лучше не садиться за "написание драйверов" вообще, пока вы задаете такие вопросы...

Answer (score 1):

По Windows. Драйверы пишутся только на C. Их можно писать либо на WDM, либо на WDF (KMDF или UMDF). Главная литература - это сайт MSDN. Начинать изучение надо с чтения документации, а затем разбора примеров из Windows DDK.